# How to Convert a string "dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS" to "HH:MM" for on-line Test Duration?

Tags: c#, datetime, model-view-controller

Code :-

```
public string TestDuration { get; set; }
 TestDuration =DateTime.Parse(dr.TestDuration.ToString()).ToShortTimeString() ;
```

I have a string of the format `dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS am/pm`, it display date and time in my view, I need hours and minutes for online test duration in format `hh:mm`.

Example: `testduration= 2hr or 2:30 mins`

Comment: What is the type and value of `dr.TestDuration`?

Comment: So what's the type of `dr.TestDuration`? All this converting to and from strings looks like a bad idea to me.

Comment: the type `dr.TestDuration` is string, and i want to convert it to time duration for online test, can u tell me how? @Artiom

Comment: @Noor Updated my answer, take a look.

Comment: so whats wrong with your code ? what is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i have a string of type DateTime

That's *not* possible. You either have `string` or have `DateTime`. Your variable type *can't* be both of them.

You can format your `DateTime` with `HH:mm` format like;

```
var result = DateTime.Parse(dr.TestDuration.ToString())
                           .ToString("hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You didn't mentioned it but, on the other hand, your `dr.TestDuration` *already* might be a `DateTime`. You *might* wanna format this value instead to generate it's string representation, parsing it to DateTime and generate it's string representation again.

```
var result = dr.TestDuration.ToString("hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

#### After your edit:

Since your `TestDuration` string and it has `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"` format, you need to parse it to `DateTime` and generate it's string representation with `hh:mm` format.

```
TestDuration = DateTime.ParseExact(dr.TestDuration, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt",
                                   CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                       .ToString("hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: The above answer worked for me right now, but what i want is i need to change the fields in database from start time to end time and then count the time for online test.. thanks for the time. @Soner Gonul